# Visual Studio Code unable to retrieve salesforce installed package smaple gallery project 'Recipe'

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Installed salesforce sample gallery project 'Recipe' in my development org directly from GitHub using the 2nd option "Installing Recipes using an Unlocked Package".
I created the project in VS using "Create Project using manifest". And finally, right-click on package.xml and click on "Retrieve source in manifest org".
But unable to get the source of this project using VS code. I created one LWC and getting that in VS.

Though I am getting 'Recipe' package by using 'The Welkin Suite tool'. 
Since Welkin is trial version so want to 'Recipe' code using VS code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install it into your Dev Org? What tools/commands are you using to try and get the source back out of the org to view/edit in VS Code? But it will be much easier to follow the instructions [at the repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) to clone the repo using git for local development, rather than trying to get the code back out of your Dev Org.

Comment: Updated the main contents with all information. Yes, I can clone the repo using git. Thanks for this info. Still curious why VS code is unable to download a package from salesforce.